# Unable to boot Ubuntu 12.04 LTS due to timeout=-1

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2

I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in my Mac Mini with OS X Lion.

Unfortunately I have set the timeout as -1 in the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file, and Ubuntu displays a menu screen to select an OS to boot (Ubuntu or Mac) during Grub session.

But another unfortunate thing, my keyboard does not work during the GRUB session.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Live-CD/USB, and increase the timeout value to a positive number.

It may also be possible to mount your boot/root partition from OS X and make the change there.

For future reference, changes in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` do not persist; you should edit `/etc/grub/default` instead.

Comment: Thanks very much, I have done this with my live USB. But, I wonder how the Linux system allow this, without asking for any password to do this? It seems anyone can boot my machine using a USB thumb drive, and do disaster to my system! Isn't it a security hole in the Linux system?

Comment: Anyone with physical access to plug in the USB can simply wipe the hard disk or remove the hard disk or just "steal" your laptop/desktop! Controlled physical access/security is the first security measure :)